# How to add an HTTP Header to all outbound HTTP Requests in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I would like to add an HTTP Header to all outbound HTTP Requests from my ASP.NET Core website (similar to the Application Insights [correlation headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation#correlation-headers))

I have tried adding a `DelegatingHandler` in my `Startup.cs`:

```
services
  .AddHttpClient(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.Options.DefaultName)
  .AddHttpMessageHandler<OutboundHttpRequestHandler>();
```

But it appears if `IHttpClientFactory` is not used, this DelegatingHandler is not executed.

How can I hook into all outbound HTTP Requests from my ASP.NET Core website?

Comment: How are your clients instantiated if not using the client factory?

Comment: I can not say for certain for all current/future clients. These are not necessarily clients that I create within my C# code, but clients created by 3rd party libraries, etc.